# Run if conditions in Parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if findmnt --source UUID=309689b5-ea5c-4175-84c7-192631553eab --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple8TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple8TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
    udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
    udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
    echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB"
fi

if findmnt --source UUID=151cf7f0-461a-416f-8e44-63d799418958 --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple6TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple6TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
    udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
    udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
    echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB"
fi
```

Here, it would be better if both if-fi code blocks run in parallel. However, the stdout & stderr within the if-fi code block should come in group (I mean their output should not overlap). What I mean is:

the stdout & stderr of following three lines should show after we have reached the end of *first* if-fi code block.

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB"
```

the stdout & stderr of following three lines should show after we have reached the end of *second* if-fi code block.

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB"
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialise those outputs (and errors), you'd have to save at least one of them temporarily:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
umask 077 # for temp files that we recreate
if findmnt --source UUID=309689b5-ea5c-4175-84c7-192631553eab --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple8TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple8TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
    udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB &&
      udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB &&
      echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB"
fi & pid=$!

out==() err==()
if findmnt --source UUID=151cf7f0-461a-416f-8e44-63d799418958 --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple6TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple6TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
    udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB &&
      udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB &&
      echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB"
fi > $out 2> $err || ret=$?

wait $pid || ret=$?

# dump the second job's errors on stderr
cat<$err >&2

# and its output to stdout:
cat<$out

# clean up the temp files
rm -f -- $out $err

# report failure if any of any of those two jobs
exit $ret
```

Here using `zsh`'s `=(...)` form of process substitution to create  temp files. With sh or bash, you could use `mktemp` or whatever command is available on your system to safely create temporary files.

Strictly, speaking `=(cmd)` is not meant to be used like that as zsh deletes the temp file as soon as the command where it's expanded finishes. Here we recreate it later with the same path, so it's not strictly safe as there's a small window during which the file could have been recreated as symlink by a malicious actor.

For any number of parallel unmounts, we could factorise things a little. We could also open fds to those to-be-deleted tempfiles so they are deleted from the start addressing the issue above and sorting up clean-up:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system || exit
out=() err_read=() err_write=() out_read=() out_write=() pid=()
n=1 ret=0

stop_disk() {
  local uuid=$1 label=$2
  if
    findmnt --source UUID=$uuid \
            --source PARTLABEL=$label \
            --mountpoint /media/ismail/$label \
            --types ext4 \
            --noheadings
  then
    udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/$label &&
      udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/$label &&
      print -r "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/$label"
  fi
}

for uuid label (
  309689b5-ea5c-4175-84c7-192631553eab WDPurple8TB
  151cf7f0-461a-416f-8e44-63d799418958 WDPurple6TB
) {
  () {
     sysopen -wo cloexec -u out -- $1 &&
       sysopen -ro cloexec -u in -- $1 &&
       err_write[n]=$out err_read[n]=$in &&
       sysopen -wo cloexec -u out -- $2 &&
       sysopen -ro cloexec -u in -- $2 &&
       out_write[n]=$out out_read[n]=$in
  } =() =() || exit

  stop_disk $uuid $label >&$out_write[n] 2>&$err_write[n] &
  pid[n++]=$!
}

for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )) {
  wait $pid[i] || ret=$?
  cat <&$err_read[i] >&2
  cat <&$out_read[i]
}

exit $ret
```

(untested)

Comment: It appears that only one is working. Is there any way both if-fi will be on file. Show output when the complete work is done.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
#!/bin/bash

a() {
    if findmnt --source UUID=309689b5-ea5c-4175-84c7-192631553eab --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple8TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple8TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
        udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
        udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB
        echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple8TB"
    fi
}
b() {
    if findmnt --source UUID=151cf7f0-461a-416f-8e44-63d799418958 --source PARTLABEL=WDPurple6TB --mountpoint /media/ismail/WDPurple6TB --types ext4 --noheadings; then
        udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
        udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB
        echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/WDPurple6TB"
    fi
}
export -f a b
parallel --lb ::: a b
```

Or:

```
umnt() {
    uuid="$1"
    label="$2"
    if findmnt --source UUID="$uuid" --source PARTLABEL="$label" --mountpoint /media/ismail/"$label" --types ext4 --noheadings; then
        udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-label/"$label"
        udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-label/"$label"
        echo "Power-Off /dev/disk/by-label/$label"
    fi
}
export -f umnt
parallel --lb umnt ::: 309689b5-ea5c-4175-84c7-192631553eab 151cf7f0-461a-416f-8e44-63d799418958 :::+ WDPurple8TB WDPurple6TB
```

Comment: This is the better solution for me.